# How can I force API GET after API POST?

Tags: angular

Desired behavior: After user submits item to Form (success), force Table (same page) to call API again and refresh items.

App structure: 2 Components, a Form and a Table, each with its own corresponding Service.

-I'm working in an existing application with some questionable conventions and I don't have a good background in Angular

-I know we can just push the item to the table on the front end but I'd rather refresh the component

-Looking for a solution similar to React's Promise chaining or returning the api GET results every time we perform an API POST.

Code:

list.component

```
  public dataRulesList: Array<MonitoringRule> = [];

  constructor(private dataRulesListService: DataRulesListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateList();
  }

  public updateList() {
    this.dataRulesListService.getRuleHistory().subscribe((dataRulesList: any) => {
      this._updateHistory(dataRulesList);
    });
  }

  private _updateHistory(dataRulesList: Array<MonitoringRule>): void {
    this.dataRulesList = dataRulesList;
    this._loadHistory();
  }
  //snip
```

list.service

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private _dataRulesList: Array<MonitoringRule> = [];

  //getter - setter

  public getRuleHistory(): Observable<Array<MonitoringRule>> {
    return this._fetchRuleHistory().do((res: any) => {
      this.dataRulesList = [];
      res.forEach((rule) => {
        this.setRuleHistoryListItem(rule);
      });
    }).map(() => {
      return this._dataRulesList;
    })
  }

  public setRuleHistoryListItem(ruleHistoryResponse: any) {
    const ruleHistory = new MonitoringRule();

    //construct rule item

    this._dataRulesList.push(ruleHistory)
  }

  private _fetchRuleHistory() {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}rules/history`)
  }
```

form.component

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataRulesService: DataRulesService, private dataRulesList: DataRulesListComponent, private dataRulesListService: DataRulesListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //form logic
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm, dataRulesList = this.dataRulesList) {
    this.dataRulesService.createRuleRequest(this.rule, form, dataRulesList);
  }

  newRule(form: NgForm) {
    this.rule.reset();
    form ? form.reset() : null;
    // can I call list.updateHistory from here? Did not work.
  }
```

form.service

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private pwsNotificationService: PwsNotificationService) { }

  public createRuleRequest(rule: Rule, form: NgForm, dataRulesList: DataRulesListComponent) {
    //form logic
   this._postCreateRuleRequest(rule, form, dataRulesList)
  }

  private _postCreateRuleRequest(rule: Rule, form: NgForm, dataRulesList: DataRulesListComponent) {
    this.http.post(`${environment.API_URL}rules/create`, rule).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.pwsNotificationService.add({
        type: 'success',
        msg: `Rule Created!`,
        timeout: 5000
      });
      rule.reset();
      form.reset();
      //tried calling list.updateHistory from here
    }, () => {
      this.pwsNotificationService.add({
        type: 'danger',
        msg: `POST Request Failed. Please contact the Data Monitoring Team.`,
        timeout: 5000
      });
    }//tried adding a .complete function here);
  }
```

So you can see I don't entirely understand Observables. Need some guidance on how to make this work the way I want it to. On success in any of those places in the form component/service, I want to call the list item's .update() method. Seems this isn't working because I'm not connecting the two properly.

Would appreciate some advices.

Comment: I think one of the things I am least clear on is the use of Observable in the list service. I've read Observable is supposed to have behavior where it continues calling the API and does not close, but if this means it is supposed to auto-update it has not been succeeding. Maybe cutting it out and making a Promise here would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer in two ways.  You asked for a promise chain, which is 100% doable, but I'd recommend avoiding it because of the unnecessary http call.  Why ask the server for the information you just gave it?

#### Preferred (update data locally):

```
this.dataRulesListService.getRuleHistory().subscribe((dataRulesList: any) => {
  this.dataRulesList.push(dataRulesList);
});
```

#### Promise chain:

```
// service.ts
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

doUpdate(bar: thing): Promise<thing> {
  foo = new Subject<any>();

  this.http.post(`${environment.API_URL}rules/create`, rule).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.pwsNotificationService.add({
    type: 'success',
    msg: `Rule Created!`,
    timeout: 5000
  });
  rule.reset();
  form.reset();
  foo.complete();
}, () => {
  this.pwsNotificationService.add({
    type: 'danger',
    msg: `POST Request Failed. Please contact the Data Monitoring Team.`,
    timeout: 5000
  });

  foo.complete();
}


  return foo.toPromise();
}


// whatever calls the service method doUpdate
this.service.doUpdate(formthing).then(
     (result)=>{
          // call service for get, or do processing or whatever
          // if this function returns a promise you can add more .then()
     }
); // further thens would go here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo-code:

controller:

```js
data = Observable<Record[]>;//defer sub to templ

saveAndRefresh() {
   let formData = getFormData(someFormGroup);//FormGroup param or instance var

   //assign ret Obs to this.data
   this.data = this.myService.save(formData).mergeMap(() => {
       return this.myService.getData();//refresh data
   });
}
```

template:

```
<form or button (click or ngSubmit)="saveAndRefresh()">
...
   <tr *ngFor="let d of (data | async)" ...>
```

Comment: Are you calling .save and .getData on the same service? My problem is that the service/component responsible for submitting the data and the service responsible for displaying it are separate. I want to call the getData func from within my saveData success logic but finding this doesn't work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question before I saw these answers with something called EventEmitter:

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Now, if I'm understanding correctly, this is deprecated, but it worked and I may as well include it in case it helps somebody else.

In the service that executes the POST:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

//in class
eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

//inside the post success, after form.reset(); in my code above:
this.eventEmitter.emit("anything");
```

In the component that calls the GET (not the service, the component):

```
import { PostService } from 'your post service location';
//import the service where you created the emitter here

//in class
constructor(xyz, private postService: PostService){ }

ngOnInit() {
  this.updateList();
  this.postService.eventEmitter.subscribe((resp) => this.updateList());
}
```

What's it do:

There's an event emitter in the POST service that emits an event. The event it emits has a string but we don't care about that.

In the GET component, we initialize it with an event listener that waits for this event. Once again, we get a response (resp) which we do not care about. We are just waiting for an event - any event - and we will call updateList() which will make a new API call and update our component.

No idea why this works and the solution I had before wouldn't but hey - if it works, it works.